# Why md5 is mentioned in rpm signature verification output with --nodigest option

Tags: security, rpm, gpg-signature

I was validating a gpg key with following command.

```
rpm --checksig <rpm name> --nodigest
```

My rpm is signed with RSA/SHA256 algorithm.

The question is: Why my output has (md5) in it.

Output:`rsa (md5) pgp OK`

When i run the same command with -v (verbose) enabled, it has no mention of md5

Output:

```
   Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID b1275ea3: OK
   V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID b1275ea3: OK
```

Comment: I don't know which version of rpm utility and which distribution you are using but the up-to-date Fedora doc : https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-check-rpm-sig.html explains it. The new command to use is `rpmkey`. If you run it with `-Kv' option it will output a MD5 Digest section which is there to ensure your package hasn't been modified during transfer.

Comment: I agree that the integrity check is needed, but by doing --nodigest i am saying that i am not interested in checking this and just need signature validations. Went through some rpm code and found below :     case RPMSIGTAG_PGP:
        n = (upper ? "(MD5) PGP" : "(md5) pgp"); that means for RPMSIGTAG_PGP append this string with output, but still the question remains why md5?

Comment: http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-checksig-using-rpm-k.html here it says that a checksum is computed both at build and verification times, and it seems it's using md5 hashing function for that purpose. But I agree with you this option looks like it's not working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

When signatures were added to RPM last century, the only commonly available digital signature implementation was PGP (which at the time was RSA/MD5).

The terse form of rpm --checksig output was an early attempt to supply additional user information and added (md5) to the output.

The real flaw with rpm --checksig is that the output attempted to summarize very complex integrity checks within a single line using upper and lower case and parentheses, all of which is almost inscrutably nerdy.

Use -Kvv to see more useful details.

Comment: Ok, do you see this a bug with gpg utility. I was wondering if they are real MD5 checks they are doing, if yes, then that will be a problem for me, If it is just a message I am ok with that.

Comment: RPM typically uses stronger hashes than MD5 to verify packages and files, but does not prevent using MD5 by users.